# Collect data from nested ObjectIDs in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

this is the input collection in MongoDB.
I got serveral Objects which look like this.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('63b730d71833eb85b96539ce'),
     'city': 'Frankfurt a.M.',
     'department_id': 101,
     'employees': [{'_id': ObjectId('63b730dd1833eb85b9653dbb'),
                    'age': 28,
                    'awards': 1,
      ..
     'name': 'HR',
     'projects': [{'_id': ObjectId('63b730dd1833eb85b96539dc'),
                   'budget': 5250100.98,
                   'department_id': 101,
                   'end_date': '1995-04-01 00:00:00',
                   'start_date': '1990-04-23 00:00:00',
                   'title': 'nhcdruimcimbytgnkklid'},
                  {'_id': ObjectId('63b730dd1833eb85b96539ee'),
                   'budget': 5062704.46,
                   'department_id': 101,
                   'end_date': '1991-03-01 00:00:00',
                   'start_date': '1990-10-11 00:00:00',
                   'title': 'jqdewbvkvpeggckpj'},
                  {'_id': ObjectId('63b730dd1833eb85b96539f9'),
                   'budget': 1858309.73,
                   'department_id': 101,
                   'end_date': '1993-04-01 00:00:00',
                   'start_date': '1991-02-07 00:00:00',
                   'title': 'urwwnrxzcgikuo'},
                  {'_id': ObjectId('63b730dd1833eb85b96539fe'),
                   'budget': 2108710.18,
```

I was able to collect the number of projects for each department.

Question: How can I get the average project-time of each department?

I tried a projection in a pipeline like:

```
"$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "department_id": 1,
        "averageProjectTime": {
            "$divide": [
                {"$size": "$projects"},
                {"$sum": {
                    "$dateDiff": {
                        "startDate": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$projects.start_date"}},
                        "endDate": {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$projects.end_date"}},
                        "unit": "day"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

But it is not looping and just giving me an array of all start_dates and all end_dates.

I am a little bit confused about the syntax of MongoDB.
Any help appriciated. No unwind and no lookup shall be used.

Would it be helpful to remove the objectID of the nested project objects?

Kind regards,
Marcus

I tried several things an I am a little bit unsure if the objectID for each project is blocking here something.

Answer (score 0):

How you doing?

I needed transform the dates, but maybe result was you wanted.

See result in this link: https://mongoplayground.net/p/xwoK1fUKoue

Comment: Hi,

no, not really. As said "unwind" or "lookup" shall not be used here.

And "match" is not helpful here as I want to loop over the departments and then within the departments a loop over the projects to find the average project-duration. 

It is possible to prepare the data first in another way and add/calculate additional data.


Thanks,
Marcus

Comment: Checked again, i will just use "unwind" and in that case it helped me a lot.
I also used " {"$dateFromString": {"dateString": "$projects.start_date"}}," to use the date as it is. :)